# how to check a SSIS dt_ntext column an empty string or not?

Tags: ssis

I have a column with dt_ntext datatype. I want to check it is empty string or not ?
i have tried  after converting this dt_WStr  but i got an truncation error  as some column have data with length more than a dt_wstr can hold?

Please advise

Comment: YourColumn == ""

Comment: its not -a dt_str 7c\olum]n=]

Comment: Well, ok, but so what? Use that comparison in a "Conditional Split" transformation.